# Is it possible to retrieve cucumber tags?

Tags: java, cucumber

I am looking for some thing like that:

```
@tag1
Feature : My new feature ....
@tag2
Scenario ...
```

And now I want to get hold of these tags to create a generic setup.

```
@Before
public void setup() {
    String annotation = readAnnotation(...);
```

Is there any way to get hold of the annotation or annotations I have added to the features and/or scenarios my code is currently prcessing?

Comment: So you just want to get a list of all tags that you have?

Comment: yes exactly, once I can get hold of such a list, in any format, features and scenarios separated or not, I can go from there.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Pass the scenario object into the @before method. Then use getSourceTagNames() method of the scenario object.

Answer (score 0):

The way I did it was just using simple find and filter from command line like this:

```
find . -name "*.feature" -exec cat {} \; | grep @ | uniq
```

If you are not on *nix, you can use [gitbash](https://git-for-windows.github.io/) (which is free and kinda useful anyway).